# How would I put part of a Handler function into a controller in Sencha

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a handler function that creates a `Ext.window.Window`, with fields to enter data, I need o move this part of the code to a controller function, and separate it from the main ajax request, this is for code reuse purposes.

```
var win = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    title: 'New Client',
    id: 'addClientWindow',
    width: 500,
    height: 300,
    items: [{
        xtype: 'form',
        bodyPadding: 10,
        items: [{
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            title: 'My Fields',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                anchor: '100%',
                id: 'nameTextField',
                fieldLabel: 'Name',

                labelWidth: 140
            }, {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                anchor: '100%',
                id: 'physicalTextField',
                fieldLabel: 'Physical Address',

                labelWidth: 140
            }, {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                anchor: '100%',
                id: 'postalTextField',
                fieldLabel: 'Postal Address',

                labelWidth: 140
            }]
        }],
        dockedItems: [{
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            dock: 'bottom',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'button',
                id: 'cancelClientBtn',
                text: 'Cancel',
                listeners: {
                    click: function(c) {
                        Ext.getCmp('addClientWindow').close();
                    }

                }
            }, {
                xtype: 'tbspacer',
                flex: 1
            }, {
                xtype: 'button',
                id: 'saveClientBtn',
                text: 'Save',
                listeners: {
                    click: function(c) {

                        Ext.Ajax.request({
                            url: 'system/index.php',
                            method: 'POST',
                            params: {
                                class: 'Company',
                                method: 'add',
                                data: Ext.encode({
                                    name: Ext.getCmp('nameTextField').getValue(),
                                    physical: Ext.getCmp('physicalTextField').getValue(),
                                    postal: Ext.getCmp('postalTextField').getValue()

                                })
                            },
                            success: function(response) {
                                Ext.MessageBox.alert('Status', 'Record has been updated.');
                                Ext.getStore('CompanyStore').reload();
                                Ext.getCmp('addClientWindow').close();
                            },
                            failure: function() {
                                Ext.MessageBox.alert('Status', 'Failed to update record.');
                            }
                        });

                    }
                }
            }]
        }]
    }]
});

win.show();
```

The button opens this window and performs this ajax request, I just need the two separated from one another. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Which version of ExtJS are u using ?

Comment: The point of this is that I have add record buttons on multiple tabs, so basically I need the same window to be accessed by all different calls, Cause right now that code I have above is in every handler, I just need it to be accessed in one place, It is inevitably duplicating id's which is what I want to avoid

Answer (score 0):

You can define your window in a separated file and give it an alias:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyWindow', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    alias: 'widget.addclient',
    ...

    click: function(){
        var data = Ext.encode({
            name: Ext.getCmp('nameTextField').getValue(),
            physical: Ext.getCmp('physicalTextField').getValue(),
            postal: Ext.getCmp('postalTextField').getValue()
         });

         // I assume here "this" links to the window component,
         // if not, adjust accordingly
         if(this.mycallback){
            this.mycallback(data);
         }
    }

});
```

Then you can call it from other controllers and provide a callback:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',

    requires: 'MyApp.view.MyWindow',

    openWindow: function(){
        var win = Ext.widget('addclient');
        win.mycallback = this.onAddClientCallback.bind(this);
        win.show();
    },

    onAddClientCallback: function(data){
        console.log("data from window", data);
    }

});
```

Comment: I see what you are saying, what if I have multiple ajax requests and multiple different views, as in not all the views are the same, so like one could have 3 fields and another could have 4 other different views. My project structure is kinda complicated, right now each handler has the window creation code in it along with the specific ajax request

Comment: If those windows have more unique than repeated code then you can create a parent window view and/or view controller and move there some common code you want to reuse, then extend it. If there is nothing common besides that they are all windows then creating a new unique window is ok, just I would put a window code into a separated file and separated view from the controller (you are handling listeners inside the view currently, usually they should be separated into so called view controllers).